# Insert image in openpyxl

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

Is it possible to insert an image (jpeg, png, etc) using openpyxl?

Basically I want to place a generated image with a chart below it.

I don't see anything in the documentation, which seems to be a little lacking compared to the maturity of the code.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The following inserts an image in cell A1. Adjust the image location to your needs or handle the creation of the PIL image yourself and hand that to `Image()`

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test.jpg')
img.anchor = 'A1'
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('out.xlsx')
```

In older versions of openpyxl the following works:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
img = openpyxl.drawing.Image('test.jpg')
img.anchor(ws.cell('A1'))
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('out.xlsx')
```

Comment: are gif files supported?

Comment: @user299709 Of course. Did you have difficulty finding the list of formats that PIL supports?

Comment: I am using Xlsxwriter and it doesn't support embedding a gif image so im wondering if openpyxl does.

Comment: @user299709 It is clear to me that you are wondering about that. The answer lies in what file formats PIL supports and I find it difficult to believe you could not find that for yourself using google.

Comment: As of 2017, it looks like:
`openpyxl.drawing.Image`
has moved to:
`openpyxl.drawing.image.Image`

Comment: As of 2019 `img.anchor(ws.cell('A1'))` now is `img.anchor = 'A1'`

Comment: If you're working with (row, col) instead of cell notation, the following can be useful: `img.anchor = xlsxwriter.utility.xl_rowcol_to_cell(row, col)`

Comment: how to add using image blob ?

Comment: after inserting image in excel sheet, how to 100% fit that image in particular cell using openpyxl???

Answer (score 10):

Providing a full update on how to do this.  This solution uses openpyxl version 2.4.5.

I downloaded an image to my local directory, opened an existing workbook and saved with the image inserted.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from openpyxl.utils import coordinate_from_string

openpyxl_version = openpyxl.__version__
print(openpyxl_version)  #to see what version I'm running

# downloaded a .png to local directory manually from
# "https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png"

#change to the location and name of your image
png_loc = r'c:\users\me\opengraph-icon-200x200.png'

# test.xlsx already exists in my current directory 

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
my_png = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(png_loc)
ws.add_image(my_png, 'B3')
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: ws.add_image(my_png, 'B3') triggers a warning `DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function anchor (Anchors can be passed in when an image is added to a worksheet).` any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Using openpyxl version 2.5.5 and 2.5.6 (the latest stable release), I was unable to reproduce this warning, running the code as posted in my example.

Comment: My openpyxl version is less recent. I'll make sure to update it

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.merge_cells('A1:A3')
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('image.jpg')
row_number = 1
col_idx = 1
cell = ws.cell(row=row_number, column=col_idx)
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: how to add using image blob ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, I have been using openpyxl==2.5.6 (with Python3.65), and I had to use `img.anchor('A1')` instead of `img.anchor(ws.cell('A1'))`.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
img = openpyxl.drawing.Image('test.jpg')
img.anchor('A1')
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('out.xlsx')
```

Comment: how to add using image blob ?