# Insert an image from url in openpyxl

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, url, openpyxl

I would like to insert an image from URL into the xlsx file.
How could I do that with openpyxl? 
I checked the documentation but not shows how to insert an image from URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert image in openpyxl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888969/insert-image-in-openpyxl)

Answer (score 9):

There is no built-in function in `Openpyxl` to insert images through URLs. You'll need to use an Http client module for python.(example:`urllib`)

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
import PIL
import io
import urllib3

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
r = 1
ws['A1'] = 'test'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'http://myridia.com/assets/images/logo.png')
image_file = io.BytesIO(r.data)
img = Image(image_file)
ws.add_image(img, 'A2')
```

[Source: Insert image from URL in openpyxl.](http://myridia.com/dev_posts/view/1514)

Comment: Is there anyway, I can compress the image size to fix dimension lets say 250x150 from the network image?

Comment: @newbiedev looking at the [API doc](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.drawing.image.html), it doesn't seem to have options to resize the image. You could instead try doing it with `pil`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631799/7683374