# How to webscrape a table with image and export to an Excel in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to webscrape a table from the [URL](https://pantheon.world/explore/rankings?show=people&years=-3501,2020)

I'm able to scrape the tabular data using Scrapestorm tool. I'm new to python and unable to fetch the data from this [URL](https://pantheon.world/explore/rankings?show=people&years=-3501,2020).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://pantheon.world/explore/rankings?show=people&years=-3501,2020')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
```

Required output in Excel:

[image]

Is it possible to web scrape tabular data along with images from a webpage?

Comment: if its dynamic content created by javascript then beautiful soup will not do any good.

Comment: Which one would be better in that case? Are there any packages that can be used?

Comment: you can try selenium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. However, seeing as how this particular page's DOM is populated asynchronously using JavaScript, BeautifulSoup won't be able to see the data you're trying to scrape. Normally, this is where most people would suggest you use a headless browser/webdriver like Selenium or PlayWright to simulate a browsing session - but you're in luck. You don't need headless browsers or Scrapestorm or BeautifulSoup for this particular page - you only need the third-party `requests` module. When you visit this page, it happens to make an HTTP GET request to a REST API that serves JSON. The JSON response contains all the information in the table. If you log your browser's network traffic, you can see the request made to the API:

[image]

Here is what the response JSON looks like - a list of dictionaries:

[image]

[image]

From that, you can copy the API URL and the relevant query string parameters to formulate your own request to that API:

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://api.pantheon.world/person_ranks"

    params = {
        "select": "name,l,l_,age,non_en_page_views,coefficient_of_variation,hpi,hpi_prev,id,slug,gender,birthyear,deathyear,bplace_country(id,country,continent,slug),bplace_geonameid(id,place,country,slug,lat,lon),dplace_country(id,country,slug),dplace_geonameid(id,place,country,slug),occupation_id:occupation,occupation(id,occupation,occupation_slug,industry,domain),rank,rank_prev,rank_delta",
        "birthyear": "gte.-3501",
        "birthyear": "lte.2020",
        "hpi": "gte.0",
        "order": "hpi.desc.nullslast",
        "limit": "50",
        "offset": "0"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()

    for person in response.json():
        print(f"{person['name']} was a {person['occupation']['occupation']}")
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Muhammad was a RELIGIOUS FIGURE
Genghis Khan was a MILITARY PERSONNEL
Leonardo da Vinci was a INVENTOR
Isaac Newton was a PHYSICIST
Ludwig van Beethoven was a COMPOSER
Alexander the Great was a MILITARY PERSONNEL
Aristotle was a PHILOSOPHER
...
```

From here it's trivial to write this information to a CSV or excel file. You can play with the `"limit": "50"` and `"offset": "0"` key-value pairs in the `params` query string parameter dictionary, to retrieve information for different people.

EDIT - To get each person's thumbnail image, you need to construct a URL of the following form:

`https://pantheon.world/images/profile/people/{PERSON_ID}.jpg`

Where `{PERSON_ID}` is the value associated with the given person's `id` key:

```
...

for person in response.json():
    image_url = f"https://pantheon.world/images/profile/people/{person['id']}.jpg"
    print(f"{person['name']}'s image URL: {image_url}")
```

If you're using `openpyxl` for your excel files, here is a [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876451/10987432) which shows you how you can insert an image into a cell given an image URL. I would recommend you use `requests` instead of `urllib3`, however, to make the request to the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Is it possible to scrape the image on each row??

Comment: @User789 Yes, it looks like the URL for each person's image follows this pattern: `https://pantheon.world/images/profile/people/{PERSON_ID}.jpg`, where `{PERSON_ID}` would be the value of the `id` key-value pair for a given person in the JSON response. For example,  Genghis Khan has the ID `17414699`, so the URL would be `https://pantheon.world/images/profile/people/17414699.jpg`.

Comment: Please don't mind, Could you add this to the answer as well

Comment: @User789 Sure, I've edited my answer at the very bottom. Take a look.