# Excel File Corrupted by Simple Import Image using Openpyxl, with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

The problem: I am simply adding an image to an existing xl file, but the file becomes corrupted by the below script.

The specs: openpyxl= 2.5.11, python= 3.7.11, excel= 16.16.5

Related Posting: [Insert image in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888969/insert-image-in-openpyxl)

Script:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
import openpyxl

image_path =os.path.expanduser('.../logo.png')
xl_path =os.path.expanduser('.../Insert Image File.xlsx')

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(image_path) 
ws.add_image(img,'A1')

wb.save(xl_path)
```

When I open the excel file I get the below pop-ups.

[image: When I open the file I get this]
[image]

Comment: Upgrade openpyxl see https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#bugfixes

Answer (score 0):

The recent openpyxl update solved the problem.