# Not able to export matplotlib plot to excel sheet --- Plotted graph in Jupyter notebook using matplotlib to Excel

Tags: python, matplotlib

From Stackoverflow, i got following code for the task

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    Import openpyxl
    #Graph Command
    plt.scatter('Month','Balance',data=test)
    #Saving
    plt.savefig("myplot.png", dpi = 150)

    wb = load_workbook('input.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active

    img = image('myplot.png')
    img.anchor(ws.cell('A1'))

    ws.add_image(img)
    wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

But i was getting error

> "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

I change the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.drawing import image

plt.scatter('Month','Balance',data=test)
plt.savefig("myplot.png", dpi = 150)

wb = load_workbook('input.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

img = image('myplot.png')
img.anchor(ws.cell('A1'))

ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

But still same error.

Please help me in exporting multiple charts/plots to excel sheet from Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please, post full traceback you get, verbatim. Also note the capital `I` in `Import openpyxl` in first snippet...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert image in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888969/insert-image-in-openpyxl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer after some changes in the code:-

```
import openpyxl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
#plotting Graph
plt.scatter('Month','Balance',data=test)
fig.savefig('temp.png', dpi=fig.dpi)

#Saving Graph in the excel Sheet
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('temp.png')
img.anchor = 'A1'
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('out.xlsx')
```