# add image to excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

i want to add image to excel using openpyxl

for this code

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

workbook = load_workbook(filename="file1.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active

logo = Image("logo.jpg")

sheet.add_image("logo.jpg", "A3")
workbook.save(filename="hello_world_logo.xlsx")
```

i got this error

```
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/drawing/image.py", line 43, in __init__
image.close()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 514, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: close
```

any idea ?

Comment: what happens if you pass the filename and not the `Image` object?

Comment: i dont understand what do u mean ? - i should pass the image right ?

Comment: I don't know. I'm suggesting you try not passing the image. Experimentation. Trial and error. All that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888969/insert-image-in-openpyxl may be quite helpful in getting this to work

Comment: i saw this link ebfore posting and i still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

try: sheet.add_image(logo, "A3")