# Adding An Image To A Specific Cell In Excel With Python

Tags: python, excel, image, openpyxl, cell

I'm having trouble adding an image to a cell in Excel using Python. I'm able to add an image *as a cover* but I cannot add it *inside a cell*.

Is there a way to do so, or is it just not supported by openpyxl?

Here is the code that adds it as a cover (*which I don't want*):

```
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image("img.txt")
img.anchor = 'A1'
worksheet.add_image(img)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert image in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888969/insert-image-in-openpyxl)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych No, This Inserts The Image As A Cover (floating in the sheet), I need It inside a cell

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, set the image properties to "Move and size with cells"? You state in one comment to an answer regarding the image; *" not in a position where it can be just dragged and moved"* How do you do that in Excel?

Comment: You cannot put images inside cells; they can only be anchored to them.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge `openpyxl` library does not provide direct support for placing images inside cells. I might be wrong because I read their documentation more than a year ago it might updated now.

However, you can get almost similar results by resizing the image to fit the cell and manually positioning it within it.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

img = Image("img.txt")

img.width = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).width
img.height = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).height

cell = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1)

left = cell.column_letter + str(cell.row)
top = str(cell.row)

img.anchor = f'{left}:{left}'
img._position = (left, top)

worksheet.add_image(img)
workbook.save('output.xlsx')
```

It might not be perfect for you, but it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score -2):

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book()
sheet = wb.sheets[0]

img_path = r"path/to/your/image.jpg"

sheet.pictures.add(img_path, name='MyPicture', left=sheet.range('A1').left, top=sheet.range('A1').top, width=100, height=100)

wb.save('output.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I want, I need the picture to be within only one cell, not in a position where it can be just dragged and moved

Answer (score -2):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

img_path = "path/to/your/image.jpg"

img = Image(img_path)
ws.add_image(img, 'A1')


ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = img.width / 6 
ws.row_dimensions[1].height = img.height / 18 

wb.save("output.xlsx")
```